# Use regex to select line by line instead of every line at once?

Tags: regex

I want to alter playlists and remove everything between and including forward slashes.

Right now I have this regex working:

```
\/[^\]]*\/\W*
```

Converts this:

```
/Users/jimmy/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Godflesh/Streetcleaner/01 Like Rats.m4a
```

To this:

```
01 Like Rats.m4a
```

---

However, I want this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:314,Hey Man Nice Shot - Filter
/Users/jimmy/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Filter/Short Bus/01 Hey Man Nice Shot.mp3
#EXTINF:173,Biscuits For Smut - Helmet
/Users/jimmy/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Helmet/Betty/03 Biscuits For Smut.mp3
#EXTINF:267,Like Rats - Godflesh
/Users/jimmy/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Godflesh/Streetcleaner/01 Like Rats.m4a
```

To be filtered to end up like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:314,Hey Man Nice Shot - Filter
01 Hey Man Nice Shot.mp3
#EXTINF:173,Biscuits For Smut - Helmet
03 Biscuits For Smut.mp3
#EXTINF:267,Like Rats - Godflesh
01 Like Rats.m4a
```

But with:

```
\/[^\]]*\/\W*
```

I end up with this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:314,Hey Man Nice Shot - Filter
01 Like Rats.m4a
```

How can I alter that regex to not remove everything between forward slashes in all the text at once?  I just want it to do it line by line.

Here it is in action:

https://regex101.com/r/RhdWA5/13

Comment: Your problem is with this part: `[^\]]*`. It causes your regex to continue capturing other lines. Changing to `.*` Fixes the problem, but then you also need to add the global option so it won't return after the first match. [`\/.*\/`](https://regex101.com/r/RhdWA5/18)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have updated your regex into:

```
^\/[^\n]*\/
```

After substitution by nothing it gives:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:314,Hey Man Nice Shot - Filter
01 Hey Man Nice Shot.mp3
#EXTINF:173,Biscuits For Smut - Helmet
03 Biscuits For Smut.mp3
#EXTINF:267,Like Rats - Godflesh
01 Like Rats.m4a
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/RhdWA5/16

Comment: Perfect thank you!  I'm not able to upvote you I suppose because I'm too new on the forum.

Comment: @JammyTone: it looks like you have reached it! Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
\/.*\/
```

full regex should be like this, enabling global option:

```js
new regExp(/\/.*\//ig)
```

and end up like this:

```php
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:314,Hey Man Nice Shot - Filter
01 Hey Man Nice Shot.mp3
#EXTINF:173,Biscuits For Smut - Helmet
03 Biscuits For Smut.mp3
#EXTINF:267,Like Rats - Godflesh
01 Like Rats.m4a
```

I made it an example also https://regex101.com/r/RhdWA5/17

Comment: I'm too new to the forum to upvote you, but I wanted to thank you nonetheless for you help.

Answer (score 2):

This regex should solve the problem:

`[^\/]+\.[\w\d]+`

It matches just the filenames.

**Working example**: https://regex101.com/r/FobLOT/1

Comment: Thank you, but it appears to work in reverse for what I needed.  It was solved by others but I want to thank you for helping!